# Java application doesn't apply enviroment variable inside docker container

Tags: java, postgresql, docker, docker-compose

I am trying to deploy my application in docker (on Windows 10), in compose with a Postgres container. When I execute docker-compose up, I see the following log:

```
Starting postgres ... done
Recreating application ... done
Attaching to postgres, application
        postgres |
        postgres | PostgreSQL Database directory appears to contain a database; Skipping initialization
        postgres |
        postgres | 2021-08-20 14:51:49.721 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv4 address "0.0.0.0", port 5432
        postgres | 2021-08-20 14:51:49.721 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv6 address "::", port 5432
        postgres | 2021-08-20 14:51:49.741 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"
        postgres | 2021-08-20 14:51:49.858 UTC [21] LOG:  database system was interrupted; last known up at 2021-08-20 14:50:34 UTC
        postgres | 2021-08-20 14:51:51.363 UTC [21] LOG:  database system was not properly shut down; automatic recovery in progress
        postgres | 2021-08-20 14:51:51.377 UTC [21] LOG:  redo starts at 0/1661A88
        postgres | 2021-08-20 14:51:51.377 UTC [21] LOG:  invalid record length at 0/1661AC0: wanted 24, got 0
        postgres | 2021-08-20 14:51:51.377 UTC [21] LOG:  redo done at 0/1661A88
        postgres | 2021-08-20 14:51:51.471 UTC [1] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
```

Then the container of my application tries to start and after the banner "Spring Boot" etc. I get an error:

```
application | 2021-08-20 14:52:23.440 ERROR 1 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool        : HikariPool-1 - Exception during pool initialization.
application |
application | org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Connection to localhost:5432 refused. Check that the hostname and port are correct and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections.
application |   at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:303) ~[postgresql-42.2.20.jar!/:42.2.20]
```

Here is my docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3"

services:
  db:
    image: postgres:11.13-alpine
    container_name: postgres
    ports:
    - 5432:5432
    volumes:
      - ./pgdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_DB=my_db
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=root
      - PGDATA=/var/lib/postgresql/data/mnt
    restart: always
  app:
    build: .
    container_name: application
    ports:
      - 8085:8085
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_HOST=db
    restart: always
    links:
      - db
```

my Dockerfile:

```
FROM openjdk:11
ADD target/my-app.jar my-app.jar
EXPOSE 8085
ENTRYPOINT ["java" , "-jar", "my-app.jar"]
```

application.properties:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://${POSTGRES_HOST}:5432/my_db
spring.datasource.username=postgres
spring.datasource.password=root
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none
spring.liquibase.change-log=classpath:liquibase/changelog.xml
logging.level.org.springframework.jdbc.core = TRACE
```

What is the problem? Why my application looking for Postgres on localhost and doesn't apply enviroment variable? Inside docker container the host for postgres should be different, isn't it? I have even tried to hardcode postgres host in application.properties to jdbc:postgresql://db:5432/my_db , but it continue to use localhost. How can I fix it?

Comment: Add your `Dockerfile` also to the question

Comment: Maybe on your application what you see is not what it does... Try to add logs before and after the connection to show the real connection string.

Comment: Why are you not building the jar in docker itself? You should be using Multi stage build for building the jar file and then copying it in the final image

Comment: If you are building the jar locally as it seems, it may be setting `POSTGRES_HOST` to `localhost` instead of `db`. For starters try building it locally, but define `export POSTGRES_HOST=db` and try again. Also, it seems you are sharing the local storage for Postgres with the container, through the volume. Is this intentional?

Answer (score 0):

try to use in this way

```
environment:
        POSTGRES_HOST: db
```